# Debug npm library(build using noidejs, nestjs and typescript ) from the consuming nestjs API app

Tags: npm

`nodecore` npm library was created with all helper functions like `filters, interceptor, logger, pipe, etc.`

At present, It was not published to the npm server. Created `tgz` file and refers to that in consuming app. It will be published when the library is built with the required functionalities. I am unable to debug the `nodecore` npm library from consuming the app.

To overcome this problem, I copied the library code to the consuming app and referred the service, module, etc to a local folder.

I have to debug the npm library from consuming since the library needs `data/context` from the consuming app, I cannot debug the library alone.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I could debug the NPM library developed by our self using npm link.